# Performance of a primary key lookup in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, realm

I've recently done some benchmarking, and it seems like looking up another object by primary key:

```
let foo = realm.object(ofType: Bar.self, forPrimaryKey: id)
```

is more efficient (and in this specific case more readable), than trying to set the property directly as:

```
class Other: Object {
    @objc dynamic var relation: Bar? = nil
    let list = List<Bar>()
}
```

My benchmarking wasn't too thorough though (used only one element in the list, etc.) and I'm wondering if this is actually the case.

Intuition makes me think primary key lookup AND using the `relation` property above would be O(1) or O(logn). With 1,000,000 records and 1,000,000 lookups:

> primary key: ~10s
>
> `relation` property: ~12s
>
> `list` property: ~14s

In summary: what is the performance of Realm's object(ofType:forPrimaryKey:) lookup?

Extra credit: when is it beneficial to use `LinkingObjects`, `List`s, etc.? Assuming it's just a readability / convenience wrapper of some sort. In my case it has been more messy / bug prone, so I'm assuming I'm not using Realm in the way it was intended.

Comment: I hope you know that Realm is a relational database, so `List` and `LinkingObjects` have quite a few use cases other than being "convenience wrappers of some sort"...

Comment: It's not really relational though.

Comment: Exactly, they refer to it as an object database.. which is why I'm trying to figure out the correct use case for `List` and `LinkingObjects`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm isn't a relational database like SQLite. Instead, data is stored in [B+ trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree). All the data for a given property on a given model type is stored within a single tree, and all data retrieval (whether getting a property value or a linked object) involves traversing such a tree.

Furthermore, when a Realm is opened, the contents of the entire database file are `mmap`ed into memory. When you use one of the Realm SDKs, the objects you create (e.g. `Object` instances) are actually thin wrappers that store a conceptual pointer to a location in the database file and provide methods to directly read from and write to the object at that location. Likewise, relationships (such as object properties on a model) are references to nodes elsewhere in the tree.

This means that retrieving an object requires the time it takes to traverse the database data structures to locate the required information, plus the time it takes to instantiate an object and initialize it. The latter is effectively a constant-time operation, so we want to look primarily at the former.

As for the situations you've outlined...

- If you already know your primary key value, getting an object takes `O(log n)` time, where `n` is the number of objects of that particular type in the database. (The time it takes to retrieve a `Dog` is irrespective of the number of `Cat`s the database contains.)
- If you're naively implementing a relational-style foreign key pattern, where you model a link to an object of type `U` by storing a primary key value (like a string) on some object of type `T`, it will take `O(log t)` time to retrieve the primary key value (where `t` is the number of `T`s), and `O(log u)` time to look up the destination object (as described in the previous bullet point; `u` = the number of `U`s).
- If you're using an object property on your model type `T` to model a link to another object, it takes `O(log t)` time to retrieve the location of the destination object.
- Using a list introduces another level of indirection, so retrieving the single object from a one-object list will be slower than retrieving an object directly from an object property.

Object, list, and linking objects properties are not intended to be an alternative to looking up objects via primary keys. Rather, they are intended to model [many-to-one](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#many-to-one), [many-to-many](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#many-to-many), and [inverse](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships) relationships, respectively. For example, a `Cat` may have a single `Owner`, so it makes sense for a `Cat` model to have a object property pointing to its `Owner`. A `Person` may have multiple friends, so it makes sense for a `Person` model to have a list property containing all their friends (which may contain zero, one, or many other `Person`s).

Finally, if you're interested in learning more, the entire database stack is open source (except for the sync component, which is a strictly optional peripheral component). You can find the code for the core database engine [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-core). We also have an older article that discusses the high-level design of the database engine; you can find that [here](https://academy.realm.io/posts/jp-simard-realm-core-database-engine/).

Comment: That's an excellent explanation and thanks for the link. To use your example, we have a `Person` data set that is too large to fit on the mobile client (different database), so need to look up by id lazily from the server. This makes more sense looking at it this way though. Thanks!